# Rounding in mql4

Tags: mql4

Used in mql4 language NormalizeDouble() function sometimes does not work properly. You can see in the example below.

```
double value=0.9731300000000001;
double value2=NormalizeDouble(value,Digits);
Print(value2);
```

As a result, although I want to get the result of 0.97313, the result is 0.9731300000000001. How can I fix.

```
double Yuvarla(double Sayi) 
{ 
    double _sayi1=MathRound(Sayi*MathPow(10,Digits)); 
    double _sayi2=_sayi1/MathPow(10,Rakam); 
    return _sayi2; 
}
```

this method didn't work either

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Use the [edit] link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type Double saves the result correctly, but I noticed a problem when printing it to the screen. When I write to the screen as DoubleToString(data,Digits()) there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of NormalizeDouble () must be 5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use DoubleToString then convert it back to double, then it should be fine.

Comment: Your answer is fundamentally incorrect. The problem is your not understanding floating point and that some numbers can't be represented exactly. see [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).